# Insert data to database from CSV file. Only inserts last row

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I read in data from a csv file, and want to insert it into my database. The issue is that it only inserts the last row in the CSV file each time. However when i print my $sq1 to screen it shows all 48 inserts with the different values that they should have. Could anyone tell me why it only inserts one row into the database?

```
<?php
// Did modify login values for privacy
$servername = "10.100.";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "abc123";
$dbname = "informationdata";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$file = fopen("ALMGrade.csv","r");

while(! feof($file)){

 $ar =fgetcsv($file);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO gradetable_copy (Grade, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5, Grade6)
VALUES ('$ar[0]', '$ar[1]', '$ar[2]', '$ar[3]', '$ar[4]', '$ar[5]', '$ar[6]' )";
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
}
fclose($file);




if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Query execution should be inside loop,check below  :

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

Will be in while loop instead after loop is over as it executing insert query only once after coming out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the execution of query (`$conn->query($sql)` ) inside while:

```
while(! feof($file))
{
 $ar =fgetcsv($file);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO gradetable_copy (Grade, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3, Grade4, Grade5, Grade6)
VALUES ('$ar[0]', '$ar[1]', '$ar[2]', '$ar[3]', '$ar[4]', '$ar[5]', '$ar[6]' )";
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
     {
      echo "New record created successfully";
     } 
else 
     {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Have one more question if you have time, I need to make the file run say once every two hours. From what I am reading a Cronjob should be used, any way you could help show me where this would go and what is needed?